# Can I say 'right up' as a request to have a ship righted?

Tags: idioms, imperatives

According to Merriam Webster, the word 'right' can be used as a verb meaning "to make a ship upright".

Could it be combined with the word 'up' to make it more clear?

Like:

Sailor: The barge has capsized. Should we do something about it?

Captain: Yes, right up!

Would this be considered idiomatic english, or would the word 'up' be omitted? Also, do we need 'it' between 'right' and 'up', or could that be omitted in terse speak when giving an order?

Comment: "Right up" wouldn't be idiomatic in this context (at least to my ear). "Yes, right it!" or "Yes, right her!" are responses that occur to me.

Comment: Have you checked for "right up" + "phrasal verb"? "Stand up" + "phrasal verb" gets results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the verb is *right.* It's not a phrasal verb *right up.* It is transitive and requires an object, "Right it."

All of [Oxford/Lexico's examples](https://www.lexico.com/definition/right) illustrate this:

> we righted the capsized dinghy
> righting the economy demanded major cuts in defence spending
> she was determined to right the wrongs done to her father
> we'll see you righted

Even if it were a phrasal verb *right up,* it would still need an object, "Right it up", "Right her up."